# Como fazer um ngRepeat sem um elemento pai?

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Estou usando o Angular com Admin LTE. Preciso fazer um `ng-repeat` onde as `li` dentro de uma `ul` vão se repetir. Não posso repetir a `ul`, mas apenas as `li` dentro desse `ul`. Também não posso englobar essas `li` com um elemento pai para fazer o laço de repetição com `ng-repeat`, pois isso está quebrando o estilo, uma vez que o seletor do  css está capturando `ul.timeline > li`.

O meu código está assim, e as linhas comentadas indicam onde preciso iniciar e terminal o `ngRepeat` :

```
<ul class="timeline" >

    <!-- [ngRepeat status in os.status] precido repetir daqui -->

    <li class="time-label">
        <span class="bg-blue" ng-bind="status.nome"></span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <i class="fa fa-check bg-green"></i>
        <div class="timeline-item">
            <h3 class="timeline-header">
                Responsável: <strong ng-bind="status.pivot.usuario.nome"></strong>
            </h3>
            <div class="timeline-body">
                <strong ng-bind="status.pivot.usuario.nome" /> realizou <span ng-bind="status.nome" /> em <strong ng-bind="status.pivot.data_inicio" />.
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <!-- [endNgRepeat] até aqui -->

    <li>
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o bg-gray"></i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Não posso usar um elemento englobando as `li` que quero repetir, mas preciso que elas se repitam dentro do trecho comentando. Como fazer isso?

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito. Você quer utilizar o mesmo `ng-repeat` com os dois elementos `li`?

Comment: @Randrade preciso que o `ng-repeat` comece onde está comentado `[ngRepeat status in os.status]` e termine onde está comentado `[endNgRepeat]`. Porém não posso "englobar" com um elemento, para usar ng-repeat, pois os elementos tirariam a formatação do css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Angular você tem o [ng-repeat-start](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points) onde você pode fazer o que deseja. Seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<ul class="timeline" >
    <li class="time-label" ng-repeat-start="item in items">
        <span class="bg-blue" ng-bind="status.nome"></span>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat-end>
        <i class="fa fa-check bg-green"></i>
        <div class="timeline-item">
            <h3 class="timeline-header">
                Responsável: <strong ng-bind="status.pivot.usuario.nome"></strong>
            </h3>
            <div class="timeline-body">
                <strong ng-bind="status.pivot.usuario.nome" /> realizou <span ng-bind="status.nome" /> em <strong ng-bind="status.pivot.data_inicio" />.
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o bg-gray"></i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Dessa forma você está mostrando onde irá começar o laço com o `ng-repeat-start` e onde terminará, com o `ng-repeat-end`.

Tomei a liberdade de criar uma [demo no Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/v0uI0D58P1CDJLAwiUnG?p=preview).

Comment: Interessante +1. No momento que eu tive o problema, pensei que o Angular teria uma maneira de fazer isso através de comentários html, mas foi mais simples do que eu pensava;

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Existem várias coisas que o Angular possui e que muitos desconhecem.

Answer (score 3):

Faz tipo isso:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="item in list">
      <td>I get repeated</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
     <td>I also get repeated</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 é isso mesmo. Valeu :D